# Why has Witold Pilecki not been included in the Righteous Among the Nations?

Tags: world-war-two, poland, holocaust

Witold [Pilecki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witold_Pilecki) was a Polish resistance fighter who volunteered to enter the Auschwitz I concentration camp. From there, he organised a resistance movement and gathered intelligence on the atrocities that occured in the camp. He summarized his findings in what came later to be known as “Witold's [Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilecki%27s_Report)”, which was the first comprehensive report of the death camp obtained by the Allies.

I wonder why Mr. Pilecki has not been included in the [Righteous Among the Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Righteous_Among_the_Nations)? Finding out he has not been included came as a surprise to me, especially considering the fact that Poland has the highest amount of people that are included of all nations.

Comment: I think this could benefit from some links to the people involved. Is there perhaps anything in Witold's background that could act as a guide?

Comment: @gktscrk I've added links to wiki pages of Pilecki's bio and report. Do you think that suffices?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  I suspect that you'd have to ask the [commission in charge of bestowing the honorary title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Righteous_Among_the_Nations#Bestowing), but I'd certainly be interested in seeing if anyone here has any insight.

Comment: @MaxMuller: Yes, I think that helps clear it. Looking at the quick bio of Pilecki and the criteria, I think it's a good question.

Comment: The list is not closed. There were [15 new inductees in January of last year (2019)](https://embassies.gov.il/bratislava-en/NewsAndEvents/Pages/Righteous-Among-the-Nations-2019.aspx).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Right, I understand that. I still find it surprising that -- considering his achievements -- he hasn't been included *yet*, after all those years.

Comment: @The Anonymous Downvoter: could you please explain your motives for downvoting this question?

Comment: This question is essentially impossible to answer. Consider writing to Yad Vashem and asking if he was ever nominated (a nomination by a Jewish party is the 1st step required for the election). Maybe he never was, then you can lobby somebody to nominate him, help to collect the required documentation, etc. HSE is not a good forum for any of these.